# Were Crew Dragon's touch screens tested under 3-5 G on Earth in a centrifuge?

Tags: spacex, dragon-v2

To use a touch screen wearing a pressurized suit with gloves may be not as easy as without space suit and gloves. But what about tests done under more than Earth's gravity?

Comment: I'm also curious if testing included vibration/shaking together with a higher static acceleration as experienced during launch.

Comment: @uhoh Good point, using a touch screen while vibrating may be especially difficult.

Comment: This article in Space Daily answers the question - AFRL centrifuge part of NASA's history-making launch https://www.spacedaily.com/reports/AFRL_centrifuge_part_of_NASAs_history_making_launch_999.html

Comment: @MikeH: That article mentions the *astronauts* training in a centrifuge, but does not clearly specify if the capsule *equipment* was tested in one.

Comment: @DrSheldon You are correct. But the question was about astronaut's use of touch screens when the capsule is under acceleration, which is addressed.

Comment: @MikeH Would you like to write an answer based on the article in Space Daily?

Answer (score 5):

This answer is taken from an article in Space Daily dated 02 Jun 2020. https://www.spacedaily.com/reports/AFRL_centrifuge_part_of_NASAs_history_making_launch_999.html

About 18 months ago SpaceX/NASA astronauts on the Demo 2 flight were trained in a Dragon simulated flight deck while under g-loading reproducing those which would be experienced on actual launch and recovery. This was done using the Air Force Research Laboratory centrifuge.

The centrifuge, usually used for fighter pilot training can use interchangeable cockpits, so one was constructed to reproduce the Crew Dragon layout.

Astronauts experience g-loads in a different relative direction compared with military pilots.

*"For pilots, the G-forces are felt through the top of the head in the z-axis... "But for astronauts, the G-forces are felt mostly in the chest in the x-axis. They have to still be able to reach forward and accomplish certain tasks on their control panels."*

The tests investigated *"what happens when you're wearing a 50-pound space suit and you're going at four Gs and the suit is pressing against your skin? ...'How can that suit be constructed so it's more comfortable for the astronauts' and 'Are they still mobile - can they reach up and flip switches?'"*